# Why does printf not work in my program (Tried flushing)

Tags: c, printf, fflush

I learned Objective-C before C and now that I am going back to C, I don't understand why the `printf()` inside the loops does not work? Could someone advise me?

The program is the first challenge in the book "Programming Challenges" By Skiena and Revilla if anyone is wondering.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static int inputInt;
static int secondInt;
int returnCycleNumber(int givenNumber);

int returnCycleNumber(int givenNumber) {
    bool initial = true;
    int counter = 1;

    do
    {
        if (givenNumber % 2 != 0)
        {
            givenNumber = givenNumber * 3 + 1;
            counter = counter + 1;

            printf("\n%i", givenNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            givenNumber = givenNumber / 2;
            counter = counter + 1;

            printf("\n%i", givenNumber);
        }

        if (givenNumber == 1) {
            initial = false;
        }

    } while (initial == true && givenNumber > 1);

    return counter;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    scanf("%i %i", &inputInt, &secondInt);
    fflush(stdout);

    int arrayCount[secondInt];

    for (int counter = 0; counter == (secondInt - inputInt); counter++ ) {
        arrayCount[counter] = returnCycleNumber(inputInt + counter);
    }

    printf("\n%i", arrayCount[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect if you used a debugger and stepped through it you'd see what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

```
counter == (secondInt - inputInt)
```

You want != or <

Comment: damn i just took so long looking at everything else but that :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < (secondInt - inputInt); counter++ ) {
```